# What is the formula to determine the sample size for machine learning models?

Tags: sample-size, model

I know that as a general rule the sample size needed to build a model using n independent variables is 10xn, however, is there a more accurate formula to determine the sample size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such formula exists for the optimal sample size of machine learning models. The general answer is - it depends. There is the **Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension**, which gives a very general expression of separability of two classes, given the number of degrees of freedom of a machine learning model. The VC-dimension is mainly of theoretical interest.

The best advice is to study generalization performance as a function of training set size on an independent test set.

Specifically for ***linear*** and ***quadratic discriminant analysis*** the variance of the error rate has been derived (by approximation). The size of the training set is a parameter in these variance calculations. [G.J. McLachlan, Discriminant analysis and statistical pattern recognition (Chap. 4), Wiley].